# swift toggle between different table view cell layouts

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wonder what techniques there are when it comes to toggle between different layouts in a table view.

What I have right now is an embedded tableview/custom cell inside my VC.
It has a simple list design, an image / title.
What I would like to do is when the user press the "grid" button it will change the layout into a bigger cell, kinda like how instagram looks.

So is it possible to animate between different cell layouts in a tableview?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have used it but I am not saying that this is the ultimate way.

Here are the steps you may like to follow :

- Design two different cells with different identifiers(I did it from storyboard)
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, check for the identifiers and display the layouts accordingly.

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cellIdentifier = (self.layoutSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? "gridLayoutCell" : "listLayoutCell" //I used segment control to toggle, change the condition as per your need

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
  if(cellIdentifier == "gridLayoutCell")
  {
    //Set the values 
    cell.bigImgView.image = [yourimage] //for ex
    ...
  }

  if(cellIdentifier == "listLayoutCell")
  {
    //Set the values
    cell.thumbnailImgView.image = [yourimage] //for ex
    ...
  }
  }
  ```
- reload your tableview when toggling(layout changes)

Try this and let me know. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks will try it out, guess I can't get the animation using this method but it looks clean and easy to use two cells:
class TableViewCellOne: UITableViewCell {
class TableViewCellTwo: UITableViewCell {

Comment: Yeah.. and I have used the same custom cell, as I didn't need the seperate for each

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it's possible to change the style once it has been initialised. You can however change between your own custom cells at runtime and is probably best achieved using a protocol for different cell types.

Comment: Do you mean protocol/delegate between the "container vc" and the table view vc ?